# angularjs cannot display PDF stream in IE browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to show PDF stream received from WebApi to browser using javascript. Currennt code is working fine on Chrome. However it shows nothing in IE 10 (no error). Any idea please.

Thanks,

Server is running on ASP.NET WebApi. Basically just export the PDF stream from a report template and send back to client.

```
[Route("api/saleInvoices/getReport")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetReport(int invoiceID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //report to pdf stream
                SaleInvoiceReport report = new SaleInvoiceReport(invoiceID);
                report.CreateDocument();
                //PdfExportOptions opts = new PdfExportOptions();
                //opts.ShowPrintDialogOnOpen = true;
                //report.ExportToPdf(ms, opts);
                report.ExportToPdf(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();

                //return
                HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                string fileName = string.Format("SalesInvoice_{0}.pdf", invoiceID);
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline") { FileName = fileName };
                return ResponseMessage(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DatabaseHelper.Log(ex);

            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Client is using AngularJS service/controller/view.

Service: receive the pdf stream in bufferarray.

```
var _report = function (id) {
        //delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

        var req={
            url: sharedService.getApiUrl() + '/' + bizType + '/getReport?invoiceID=' + id,
            method: 'GET',
            //headers:{
            //    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sharedService.getToken(),
            //},
            //headers: { 'Accept': 'application/pdf' },
            responseType:'arraybuffer',
        };

        return $http(req);
    };
```

Controller: host the pdf stream in a Blob and return its trusted url.

```
saleInvoiceService.report($scope.invoice.id)
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

                var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
                //window.open(fileURL);
                //$scope.url = fileURL;

                $scope.isLoading = false;
                $scope.info = '';
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                $scope.isLoading = false;
                $scope.info = JSON.stringify(data);
            });
```

View: assign blob's trusted url in iframe.

```
<iframe ng-src="{{url}}" class="iframe-report"></iframe>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue with IE